# Override the condition from ActiveQuery->init()

Tags: yii, yii2

On Yii2 i have this code in `ProjectQuery`

```
class ProjectQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->andOnCondition(['deleted' => 0]);
        parent::init();
    }
```

Obviously the deleted condition must always apply, but there could be cases where this isn't true (for example an option for the user to see his deleted projects). How can i override this condition? Do i have to use something different from `init()` ?

(note, i want to apply this condition to all kind of queries normally, that's why i used `init()` on `ProjectQuery` and not the `ProjectSearch` class)

Comment: Why you're using `andOnCondition()` instead of `andWhere()`?

Comment: Cause it needs to be an additional condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `init()` but to override the 0 you should bind a parameter.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->andOnCondition('deleted = :deleted', [':deleted' => 0]);
    parent::init();
}
```

So to create a query that only shows the deleted projects write something like this:

```
$query = Project::find()->addParams([':deleted' => 1]);
```

To show all projects, deleted and not deleted, you could add a function to the `ProjectQuery` object to modify it accordingly.

```
public function includeDeleted() {
    $this->orOnCondition(['deleted' => 1]);
    return $this;
}
```

And then write your query like:

```
$query = Project::find()->includeDeleted();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onCondition()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#onCondition()-detail) to override existing `on` conditions:

```
public function init() {
    $this->andOnCondition('deleted = :deleted', [':deleted' => 0]);
    parent::init();
}

public function includeDeleted() {
    $this->onCondition(null);
    // remove unused param from old ON condition
    unset($this->params[':deleted']);

    return $this;
}
```

---

You can use [`where()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#where()-detail) in the same way if you want to override conditions added by `where()`, `andWhere` and `orWhere()`.

Comment: Yes, i already use an includeDeleted() function.
My question is, is there a way to declare the `andOnCondition` so if there's another find with the condition WHERE deleted = 1 the `init()` `andOnCondition` will be ignored?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that, but I would be careful with such approach. I would rather create separate models (like `AllPosts` and `Posts` for undeleted models) than rely on default condition, which sometimes should be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a class `Project` where you have overwritten the `find()` method to return a `ProjectQuery` instance, the following might be another option. I also assume that you regularely query for undeleted items, and not so often but explicitly for all/deleted items.

Another option could be to add another method to the `Project` class and remove the default initialization in the `ProjectQuery` class.

```
class ProjectQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }
    ...
}
```

And:

```
class Project extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    ...
    public static function find()
    {
        return (new ProjectQuery(get_called_class()))
               ->andOnCondition(['deleted' => 0]);
    }

    public static function findAllProjects() // or find any better name for this
    {
        return new ProjectQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to query *explicitly all* projects you would need to use this extra method `Project::findAllProjects()`. So in normal circumstances you won't have to remember that you have to modify the query in some way. No danger, that this could be forgotten.

It is still not 100% satisfying, since one could use `find()` and add `->andOnCondition(['deleted' => 1])` which would mean no records can be found. However, regarding security this is not so critical and the problem is found easily, I guess.

Comment: it cannot be used with the relations when the conditions are contradicts, like when is_deleted = false and is_deleted =true